# No exception of type AxisFault can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable

Tags: web-services, eclipse-plugin, apache-axis

I created stub for the WSDL using Axis2_Codegen_Wizard_1.3.0, but in MyWebServiceStub.java gives error "No exception of type AxisFault can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable"

I think I am missing some jar library, but don't know which one I require. Please help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am new to Soap service, and I faced this error!
Solution is pretty simple, I did not have added java JRE library to my project in which I am going to create WSDL client. So I have added JRE System Library and its running.

`Right click on project->Properties->Java Build Path->Add Library-> JRE System Library`

Select the appropriate JRE you have installed.

It works!